# Flutter Listview in a Listview scrolling weirdness

Tags: flutter

So I have a listview.builder that uses an itembuilder that calls another Listview.builder and another itembuilder.  I got help on another thread for some sizing issues and everything presents great.  The goal of the page is to have a date divider that then has a list of messages by that date, this can grow based on messages for the day and current day.  However there is some weirdness to the scolling, if you grab the divider it scrolls fine up and down, however if you hot one of the cards between the divider it only scrolls within that area. Wondered if there was a better way to accomplish the same layout result.

Any help would be great.  I put all the code form the page here and let me know if you have questions.  Again it all works good and layout is exactly what I want, just scrolls weird and not really effective.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/models.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/ChatConvoDetail.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/Settings.dart' as Admin;
import 'package:cswauthapp/HomePage.dart' as HomePage;
import 'package:cswauthapp/main.dart' as MyHomePage;
import 'package:cswauthapp/PostAuthHome.dart' as PostAuthHome;

class ChatNTDateSep extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatNTDateSep({Key key, this.title, this.mychat}) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = "/ChatNTDate";

  final ChatList mychat;
  final String title;

  @override
  _ChatNTDateSepState createState() => new _ChatNTDateSepState();
}

/// // 1. After the page has been created, register it with the app routes
/// routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
///   ChatNoThread.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new ChatNoThread(title: "ChatNoThread"),
/// },
///
/// // 2. Then this could be used to navigate to the page.
/// Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatNoThread.routeName);
///

class _ChatNTDateSepState extends State<ChatNTDateSep> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  int oid = 0;
  int pid = 0;
  int authlevel = 0;
  bool admin = false;
  int type = 0;
  String msgid = '';
  List chatlist;
  int listcount = 0;
  bool grpmsg = true;
  String sender = '';
  String receiver = '';
  String message = '';
  String oname = '';
  String pname = '';
  String sendname;
  String receivename;
  String replyto = '';
  String replyfrom = '';
  String replysub = '';
  final TextEditingController _newreplycontroller = new TextEditingController();
  String myfcmtoken = 'NONE';

  _getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //hasRef = prefs.getBool('hasRef');

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        oid = prefs.getInt('oid');
        pid = prefs.getInt('pid');
        authlevel = prefs.getInt('authlevel');
        admin = prefs.getBool('admin');
        type = 1;
        msgid = widget.mychat.msgkey;
        if (widget.mychat.grpid == '0') {
          grpmsg = false;
        } else {
          grpmsg = true;
        }
        oname = widget.mychat.oname;
        pname = widget.mychat.pname;
        myfcmtoken = prefs.getString('fcmtoken');
        if (authlevel == 0) {
          sender = 'o';
          receiver = 'p';
          sendname = widget.mychat.oname;
          receivename = widget.mychat.pname;
        } else {
          sender = 'p';
          receiver = 'o';
          sendname = widget.mychat.pname;
          receivename = widget.mychat.oname;
        }
        _getChats();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //controller = new TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _getPrefs();
  }

  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();
  var _focusnode = new FocusNode();

  _getChats() async {
    //var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/getmessages/$type/$msgid';
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/messages/getdates/$msgid';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.get(_url, headers: getAuthHeader());

    var chats = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        chatlist = chats.toList();
        listcount = chatlist.length;
        //replysub = 'Re: ' + chatlist[0]['sub'];
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() {
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _getChats();
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget mytitle;
    if (grpmsg) {
      mytitle = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.people),
          new Text('  '),
          new Text(widget.mychat.referralname)
        ],
      );
    } else {
      mytitle = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.person),
          new Text('  '),
          new Text(widget.mychat.referralname)
        ],
      );
    }

    /*Widget _grpHdr() {
      assert(grpmsg);
      return new Text(
        widget.mychat.referralname,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      );
    }

    Widget _noGrpHdr() {
      assert(!grpmsg);
      return new Text(
        widget.mychat.referralname,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      );
    }*/

    var _children = <Widget>[

      new Expanded(
        child: new RefreshIndicator(
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: _divBuilder,
            itemCount: listcount,shrinkWrap: true,
          ),
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
        ),
      ),
      new Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Chat Reply',
              labelText: 'Chat Reply:',
            ),
            autofocus: false,
            focusNode: _focusnode,
            maxLines: 2,
            controller: _newreplycontroller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
          ),
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
            onPressed: _sendReply,
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ];
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: mytitle,
        actions: getAppBarActions(context),
      ),
      body: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: _children,
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget _divBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    DateTime getdatediv = getDateDiv(index);
    return new MyChatWidget(
      datediv: getdatediv,
      msgkey: msgid,
    );

  }


  DateTime getDateDiv(int index) {
    DateTime msgdate = DateTime.parse(chatlist[index]['chatdate']).toLocal();
    return msgdate;
  }


  _sendReply() {
    if (_newreplycontroller.text.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          content: new Text("Can not submit chat message that is empty"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                }),
            /*new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('SHOW'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              }),*/
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {

      DateTime dateSubmit = new DateTime.now();
      var mymessage = _newreplycontroller.text;
      ChatMessage mychat = new ChatMessage(
          widget.mychat.msgkey,
          widget.mychat.referralname,
          replysub,
          oid,
          oname,
          pid,
          pname,
          sender,
          sendname,
          receiver,
          receivename,
          mymessage,
          dateSubmit.toString(),
          widget.mychat.grpid,
          widget.mychat.prid,
          myfcmtoken);
      _doSendReply(mychat);
    }
  }

  _doSendReply(mychat) async {

    var json = jsonCodec.encode(mychat);
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/sendchatmsg';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.post(_url, body: json, headers: getJSONHeader());

    var chatresp = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);
    if (chatresp.contains('GOOD')) {
      _getChats();
      _newreplycontroller.text = '';
      _focusnode.unfocus();
      /*Route route = new MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: new RouteSettings(name: "/Chat"),
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new Chat.Chat(title: "Loop Chat Reply"),
      );
      Navigator.of(context).push(route);*/
    } else if (chatresp.contains('EMPTY')){
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          content: new Text("Can not submit chat message that is empty"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                }),
            /*new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('SHOW'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              }),*/
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {}

  }
}

class MyChatWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyChatWidget({Key key, this.datediv, this.msgkey}) : super(key: key);

  final DateTime datediv;
  final String msgkey;

  @override
  _MyChatWidgetState createState() => new _MyChatWidgetState();
}

class _MyChatWidgetState extends State<MyChatWidget> {
  List messagelist;
  int messagecount = 0;
  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();
  var mydate = '';

  _getMessages() async {
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/messages/getbydate';
    DateChatMessage dcm = new DateChatMessage(widget.msgkey, widget.datediv.toString());
    var json = jsonCodec.encode(dcm);
    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.post(_url, headers: getAuthHeader(), body: json);

    var messages = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        messagelist = messages.toList();
        messagecount = messagelist.length;
        if (new DateFormat.yMd().format(widget.datediv) == new DateFormat.yMd().format(new DateTime.now())) {
          mydate = 'Today';
        } else {
          mydate = new DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(widget.datediv);
        }
        //replysub = 'Re: ' + chatlist[0]['sub'];
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //controller = new TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _getMessages();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _children = <Widget>[
      new Text(mydate, textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
      new Divider(
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      //new Text(new DateFormat.yMd().format(widget.datediv),),

      new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
        itemCount: messagecount,
        shrinkWrap: true,
      ),

      /*new Flexible(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
          itemCount: messagecount,
          shrinkWrap: true,
        ),
      ),*/

    ];


    return new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: _children,
      );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    ChatMessage mychat = getChat(index);
    return new ChatWidget(
      mychat: mychat,
    );
  }

  ChatMessage getChat(int index) {
    //prefs.setInt('pid', myReferralList[index]['pid']);
    return new ChatMessage(
      messagelist[index]['msgkey'],
      messagelist[index]['referralname'],
      messagelist[index]['sub'],
      messagelist[index]['oid'],
      messagelist[index]['oname'],
      messagelist[index]['pid'],
      messagelist[index]['pname'],
      messagelist[index]['sender'],
      messagelist[index]['sendname'],
      messagelist[index]['receiver'],
      messagelist[index]['receivename'],
      messagelist[index]['message'],
      messagelist[index]['submitdate'],
      messagelist[index]['pgrpid'],
      messagelist[index]['prid'],
      messagelist[index]['fcmtoken'],
    );
  }
}


class ChatWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatWidget({Key key, this.mychat}) : super(key: key);

  final ChatMessage mychat;

  @override
  _ChatWidgetState createState() => new _ChatWidgetState();
}

class _ChatWidgetState extends State<ChatWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime submitdate = DateTime.parse(widget.mychat.submitdate).toLocal();

    return new Card(
      child: new Container(
        width: 150.0,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  widget.mychat.sendname,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                new Text(' '),
                new Text(new DateFormat.Hm().format(submitdate)),
                //new Text(submitdate.toLocal().toString())
              ],
            ),

            //new Text(widget.mychat.receivename,style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            //new Text(new DateFormat.yMd().add_Hm().format(submitdate)),
            new Text('${widget.mychat.message}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    /*return new ListTile(
      leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(widget.mychat.oname[0])),
      title: new Text(widget.mychat.referralname),
      subtitle: new Text(new DateFormat.yMd().add_Hm().format(submitdate)),
      trailing: new Text(widget.mychat.sendname),
      onTap: _onTap,
    );*/
  }
}
```

Here is the latest UPDATED CODE:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/models.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/ChatConvoDetail.dart';
import 'package:cswauthapp/Settings.dart' as Admin;
import 'package:cswauthapp/HomePage.dart' as HomePage;
import 'package:cswauthapp/main.dart' as MyHomePage;
import 'package:cswauthapp/PostAuthHome.dart' as PostAuthHome;

class ChatDivided extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatDivided({Key key, this.title, this.mychat}) : super(key: key);

  static const String routeName = "/ChatDivided";

  final ChatList mychat;
  final String title;

  @override
  _ChatDividedState createState() => new _ChatDividedState();
}

class _ChatDividedState extends State<ChatDivided> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  int oid = 0;
  int pid = 0;
  int authlevel = 0;
  bool admin = false;
  int type = 0;
  String msgid = '';
  List chatlist;
  int listcount = 0;
  bool grpmsg = true;
  String sender = '';
  String receiver = '';
  String message = '';
  String oname = '';
  String pname = '';
  String sendname;
  String receivename;
  String replyto = '';
  String replyfrom = '';
  String replysub = '';
  final TextEditingController _newreplycontroller = new TextEditingController();
  String myfcmtoken = 'NONE';

  _getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //hasRef = prefs.getBool('hasRef');

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        oid = prefs.getInt('oid');
        pid = prefs.getInt('pid');
        authlevel = prefs.getInt('authlevel');
        admin = prefs.getBool('admin');
        type = 1;
        msgid = widget.mychat.msgkey;
        if (widget.mychat.grpid == '0') {
          grpmsg = false;
        } else {
          grpmsg = true;
        }
        oname = widget.mychat.oname;
        pname = widget.mychat.pname;
        myfcmtoken = prefs.getString('fcmtoken');
        if (authlevel == 0) {
          sender = 'o';
          receiver = 'p';
          sendname = widget.mychat.oname;
          receivename = widget.mychat.pname;
        } else {
          sender = 'p';
          receiver = 'o';
          sendname = widget.mychat.pname;
          receivename = widget.mychat.oname;
        }
        _getChats();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //controller = new TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _getPrefs();
  }

  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();
  var _focusnode = new FocusNode();

  _getChats() async {
    //var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/getmessages/$type/$msgid';
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/messages/getdates/$msgid';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.get(_url, headers: getAuthHeader());

    var chats = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        chatlist = chats.toList();
        listcount = chatlist.length;
        //replysub = 'Re: ' + chatlist[0]['sub'];
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() {
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _getChats();
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget mytitle;
    if (grpmsg) {
      mytitle = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.people),
          new Text('  '),
          new Text(widget.mychat.referralname)
        ],
      );
    } else {
      mytitle = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(Icons.person),
          new Text('  '),
          new Text(widget.mychat.referralname)
        ],
      );
    }


    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: mytitle,
        actions: getAppBarActions(context),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new RefreshIndicator(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: _divBuilder,
                itemCount: listcount,shrinkWrap: true,
              ),
              onRefresh: _onRefresh,
            ),
          ),
          new Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Chat Reply',
                  labelText: 'Chat Reply:',
                ),
                autofocus: false,
                focusNode: _focusnode,
                maxLines: 2,
                controller: _newreplycontroller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
              ),
              new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: _sendReply,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _divBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    DateTime getdatediv = getDateDiv(index);
    return new MyChatWidget(
      datediv: getdatediv,
      msgkey: msgid,
    );

  }


  DateTime getDateDiv(int index) {
    DateTime msgdate = DateTime.parse(chatlist[index]['chatdate']).toLocal();
    return msgdate;
  }


  _sendReply() {
    if (_newreplycontroller.text.isEmpty) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          content: new Text("Can not submit chat message that is empty"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {

      DateTime dateSubmit = new DateTime.now();
      var mymessage = _newreplycontroller.text;
      ChatMessage mychat = new ChatMessage(
          widget.mychat.msgkey,
          widget.mychat.referralname,
          replysub,
          oid,
          oname,
          pid,
          pname,
          sender,
          sendname,
          receiver,
          receivename,
          mymessage,
          dateSubmit.toString(),
          widget.mychat.grpid,
          widget.mychat.prid,
          myfcmtoken);
      _doSendReply(mychat);
    }
  }

  _doSendReply(mychat) async {

    var json = jsonCodec.encode(mychat);
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/sendchatmsg';

    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.post(_url, body: json, headers: getJSONHeader());

    var chatresp = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);
    if (chatresp.contains('GOOD')) {
      _getChats();
      _newreplycontroller.text = '';
      _focusnode.unfocus();

    } else if (chatresp.contains('EMPTY')){
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          content: new Text("Can not submit chat message that is empty"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                }),

          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {}

  }
}

class MyChatWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyChatWidget({Key key, this.datediv, this.msgkey}) : super(key: key);

  final DateTime datediv;
  final String msgkey;

  @override
  _MyChatWidgetState createState() => new _MyChatWidgetState();
}

class _MyChatWidgetState extends State<MyChatWidget> {
  List messagelist;
  int messagecount = 0;
  var jsonCodec = const JsonCodec();
  var mydate = '';

  _getMessages() async {
    var _url = 'http://$baseurl/csapi/messages/getbydate';
    DateChatMessage dcm = new DateChatMessage(widget.msgkey, widget.datediv.toString());
    var json = jsonCodec.encode(dcm);
    var http = createHttpClient();
    var response = await http.post(_url, headers: getAuthHeader(), body: json);

    var messages = await jsonCodec.decode(response.body);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        messagelist = messages.toList();
        messagecount = messagelist.length;
        if (new DateFormat.yMd().format(widget.datediv) == new DateFormat.yMd().format(new DateTime.now())) {
          mydate = 'Today';
        } else {
          mydate = new DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(widget.datediv);
        }
        //replysub = 'Re: ' + chatlist[0]['sub'];
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //controller = new TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _getMessages();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _children = [
      new Text(mydate, textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
      new Divider(
        height: 5.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),

      new Flexible(
          child: new Column(
            children: new List.generate(messagecount, (int index) {

              ChatMessage mychat = getChat(index);
              DateTime submitdate = DateTime.parse(mychat.submitdate).toLocal();
              new Card(
                child: new Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            mychat.sendname,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          new Text(' '),
                          new Text(new DateFormat.Hm().format(submitdate)),

                        ],
                      ),

                      new Text('${mychat.message}'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            ),
          ),
      ),

    ];


    return new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: _children,
    );
  }

  ChatMessage getChat(int index) {
    //prefs.setInt('pid', myReferralList[index]['pid']);
    return new ChatMessage(
      messagelist[index]['msgkey'],
      messagelist[index]['referralname'],
      messagelist[index]['sub'],
      messagelist[index]['oid'],
      messagelist[index]['oname'],
      messagelist[index]['pid'],
      messagelist[index]['pname'],
      messagelist[index]['sender'],
      messagelist[index]['sendname'],
      messagelist[index]['receiver'],
      messagelist[index]['receivename'],
      messagelist[index]['message'],
      messagelist[index]['submitdate'],
      messagelist[index]['pgrpid'],
      messagelist[index]['prid'],
      messagelist[index]['fcmtoken'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would save yourself so much trouble if you can build your date divider inside your `ChatWidget` build:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(body: new Column(

      children: <Widget>[

        new Flexible (child: new ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new ChatWidget (


              );
            })),
        new Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Chat Reply',
                labelText: 'Chat Reply:',
              ),
              autofocus: false,
              maxLines: 2,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
            ),
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: null,
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class ChatWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container (child: new Column (children: <Widget>[

      new Divider(height: 15.0, color: Colors.red),
      new Text("My Awesome Date"),
      new Divider(height: 15.0, color: Colors.red),

      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Card(
              child: new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(
                          "Awesome Child",
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        new Text(' @ '),
                        new Text("Awesome Date"),
                      ],
                    ),

                    new Text(
                        'AWESOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE'),
                  ],
                ),
              ))
        ],
      )

    ],),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Try this:

```
    Widget _divBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    DateTime getdatediv = getDateDiv(index);
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[new MyChatWidget(
      datediv: getdatediv,
      msgkey: msgid,
    ),
    ],);
  }
```

**Update**

Generate a list of cards based on the number of message for each divider like this:

```
return new Column(
      children: new List.generate(
          5, (int index) { //5 = number of cards per date
        return new Card(
          //layout design
        );
      }),
    );
```

**Update**
This is a full example of what I meant on `List.generate`:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(body: new Column(

      children: <Widget>[

        new Flexible (child: new ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Divider(color: Colors.red,),
                  new Text("Date$index"),
                  new ChatWidget(
                    //pass the number of messages for date[index]
                  )
                ],
              );
            })),
        new Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Chat Reply',
                labelText: 'Chat Reply:',
              ),
              autofocus: false,
              maxLines: 2,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
            ),
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: null,
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class ChatWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: new List.generate(
          5, (int index) { //5 = number of messages of the current dat[index]
        return new Card(
          //layout design
          child: new Text("Message$index"),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The only issue is the chat widget is for every message and I only need the divider for each group of dated messages, so there could be 1+ for each date and need a divider by date not by message which is why I did it this way.

Comment: Oh, that is exactly why you are getting Cards scrolling only in each group, it fetches each group in ListView of its own.

Comment: Yep, thats why I was wondering if there was a better way to do it to get the layout I need but not have the scrolling behavior.

Comment: In _divBuilder have you tried to return a Column instead of ChatWidget and add the ChatWidget as a single child for this Column, check the edited section in the answer for clarification.

Comment: Appears to be the same behavior, no change, still can not scroll by grabbing a card, only by grabbing the divider.

Comment: Can we agree that the second ListView is not actually needed ?

Comment: I could agree as long as the list of messages can be presented.  I just could not find another way to present them accept in a listview.builder.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to display the data without a list view?  The data I have comes from a restapi and gets put into a list for use.

Comment: I am thinking of a layout. Actually one solution is that if you pass the number of messages under a single date and make your ChatWidget return a Column of list of Cards equal to that number using List.generate, I am not sure about how performant the app will be though.

Comment: Do you have an example of the use of List.generate?

Comment: So I tried this, I put it in the MyChat after the Divider, it goes in, but still gives an error, I also explicitly put it in my return to test, I keep getting ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1688 pos 14:

Have you seen this before?

Comment: So what I think is complicating this, is that I have to get data twice, I get data first to get the list of dates, thats where the original Listview.builder comes in, I then have to build it with the divider and get the list of messages on my second data call, then pass to the widget, I finally got everything to pass to the final widget and run list generate, but still got the same result along with overflows, etc... I follow and implemented your suggestion, but I think because it does not take into account the 2 datasets and then need to loop over both one needs the ListView to scroll.

Comment: I have tried several other iterations.  The current one is I have the original ListView.builder that calls an item builder that creates the widget with the date divider and a List.generate to return the column and card without calling the last widget.  I can see all data get populated, but still get the same framework failed assertion as above.  Any other thoughts to account for the 2 data sets needed to make it work?

Comment: I do not really understand the issue or the error you get, maybe update the post with more information.

Comment: I just put the latest iteration of the code, that still give the Failed Assertion Error in the previous comment.

Comment: Is this the complete error message ? From this alone it is unclear, does it work eventually or does it not work at all? I am having a guess it is because you are starting messageCount = 0 ?

Comment: This is what you get when you start null
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyChatWidget(dirty, state:
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '>' was called on null.

Comment: The regular message is this in the IDE.
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1688 pos 14:

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Comment: I am not saying you start it as null as a solution, but starting it as zero does not make sense either, is it possible that you do all your API calling in one class and then pass all the data you need to your ChatWidget ? If you do not want to do this then try using FutureBuilder in your ChatWidget instead of using initState to do your async jobs.

Comment: I could do all the API calls in one class, however it changes based on the number of dates coming back with messages in them.  So tracking could be an issue.  I will look at Future builder and see if that helps.